Why is this code flagged as having performance issue by static analysis tool?
I'm running cppcheck tool on some code and it reports me a performance issue in some code verifying a map does not have a value before inserting a new one.
I isolated the code in a MCVE snippet (that makes no sense...but illustrates the issue):
std::map<int, float*> myMap;
myMap[1] = new float(3.0f);

for ( size_t pos = 0; pos != 10; ++pos )
{
    if ( myMap.find( pos ) == myMap.end() )
    {
        myMap[pos] = new float(4.0f);
    }
}

CppCheck reports (performance,ID=stlFindInsert) Searching before insertion is not necessary.
Actuaually, it is necessary to prevent leak by replacing the old value by a new one...and by the way you may not want to replace the old value if any....
How am I supposed to write the code better to prevent this performance issue?

@john: Which leaks memory if pos is already in the map.

Why are you using pointers to single float values? What problem is that supposed to solve?

On a somewhat related note, unless you have very specific requirements you shouldn't really use float for floating point numbers, use double instead.

because you are unecessarily calling new (useless use of new is a thing in C++), in fact in current C++ it is not nearly needed as much as you think. Just make a std::map<int,float>. Also you might want to use try_emplace if you don't want to overwrite keys

@BillLynch Good point, I deleted my comment. Not sure why a pointer is being used in the first place.

@Someprogrammerdude: Let's assume that they have been kind to us, and created a MCVE.

And unless you need the map do be ordered on the key (which might be useful sometimes, but usually not) use std::unordered_map instead.

Side note, even if your actual code uses a class instead of float. Still don't use new/std::make_unique unless you need polymorphism otherwise just ensure your type is movable.

@Someprogrammerdude: This is just a MCVE, to illustrate a valid code generating the warning

@BillLynch That assumption should not be granted here, as I never see it granted anywhere else. It's right to ask about it in a comment. If there is a good reason, it should be [edit]ed into the question.

float on heap is strange thing to do. But if you do it you should use std::make_unique<float>(4.0f) and std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<float>>.

You actually do 2 look-ups whereas only 1 is needed.
You can use insert/emplace instead (and to avoid memory leak, insert nullptr instead and overwrite it):
std::map<int, float*> myMap;
myMap[1] = new float(3.0f);

for ( size_t pos = 0; pos != 10; ++pos )
{
    if (auto [it, inserted] = myMap.emplace(pos, nullptr); inserted)
    {
        it->second = new float(4.0f);
    }
}

Another way, if you didn't insert default value in the map before might be
std::map<int, float*> myMap;
myMap[1] = new float(3.0f);

for ( size_t pos = 0; pos != 10; ++pos )
{
    auto& pointer = myMap[pos]; // operator [] does the default instertion,
                                // if not already present
    if (pointer == nullptr)
    {
        pointer = new float(4.0f);
    }
}


I would figure out that the general case may require to overwrite the old value and delete that

sorry I deleted the comment you replied to, you are right I thought the issue would be with deleting the old item from the map in replacement but the actual example code doesn't do replacement.

the second example is a neat trick

OK, I see the idea, to lookup once only. Thank you

Typo it->second = new float(4.0f);

To avoid a double map lookup you can search for the item using equal_range, then using insert with passing the result the iterator hint.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/equal_range
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert
The result is that you only pay the logarithmic time to insert the item for the equal_range call, while insert should happen in amortized constant time

Better performance that my solution (especially if object to construct is heavy).

Better in theory, but a lot of stdlib implementations ignore the hint, since devs kept passing bad hints :/
